# How to handle $null in the pipeline

Tags: powershell

I often have the following situation in my PowerShell code: I have a function or property that returns a collection of objects, or `$null`. If you push the results into the pipeline, you also handle an element in the pipeline if `$null` is the only element.

Example:

```
$Project.Features | Foreach-Object { Write-Host "Feature name: $($_.Name)" }
```

If there are no features ($Project.Features returns $null), you will see a single line with "Feature name:".

I see three ways to solve this:

```
if ($Project.Features -ne $null)
{
  $Project.Features | Foreach-Object { Write-Host "Feature name: $($_.Name)" }
}
```

or

```
$Project.Features | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null) | Foreach-Object { 
  Write-Host "Feature name: $($_.Name)" 
}
```

or

```
$Project.Features | Foreach-Object { 
  if ($_ -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "Feature name: $($_.Name)" }
  }
}
```

But actually I don't like any of these approaches, but what do you see as the best approach?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't think *anyone* likes the fact that both "foreach ($a in $null) {}" and "$null | foreach-object{}" iterate once. Unfortunately there is no other way to do it than the ways you have demonstrated. You could be pithier:

```
$null | ?{$_} | % { ... }
```

the `?{$_}` is shorthand for `where-object {$_ -ne $null}` as `$null` evaluated as a boolean expression will be treated as `$false`

I have a filter defined in my profile like this:

```
filter Skip-Null { $_|?{ $_ } }
```

Usage:

```
$null | skip-null | foreach { ... }
```

A filter is the same as a function except the default block is process {} not end {}.

**UPDATE**: As of PowerShell 3.0, `$null` is no longer iterable as a collection. Yay!

-Oisin

Comment: The problem with the concise shorthand is that it will reject anything that coerces to `false`, which includes things like `0`, `""`, `@()`, `@(0)`, ... I'd probably expect `Skip-Null` to actually skip only `$null`. I know that in the context of this question the result is the same, but for a filter that might be used elsewhere too ...

Comment: sadly `@() |?{$false}` still returns $null instead of returning an empty list

Comment: [$null should be on left side of equality comparison](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1021) (`Where-Object {$Null -ne $_}`), because `$_` could theoretically hold a (sub) array with multiple items where just one item is `$Null` which will incorrectly filter out the object.

Answer (score 12):

If you can modify your function, have it return an empty collection/array instead of $null:

```
PS> function Empty { $null }
PS> Empty | %{'hi'}
hi

PS> function Empty { @() }
PS> Empty | %{'hi'}
```

Otherwise, go with what Oisin suggests although I would suggest a slight tweak:

```
filter Skip-Null { $_|?{ $_ -ne $null } }
```

Otherwise this will also filter `0` and `$false`.

**Update 4-30-2012:** This issue is fixed in PowerShell v3.  V3 will not iterate over a scalar $null value.

Comment: Why can't I only accept one answer! They are both great, thank you guys! I gave Oisin the "answer", Keith already has the most point:-)

Comment: What are the chances that I happened to be looking at this very answer when you edited it nearly 17 months after it was posted?  Is there a cmdlet to calculate that?

Comment: @BACON It's definitely not coincidental.  I noticed via my SO inbox that you had posted a comment on one of my answers.  :-)  Just thought it would be good to point out that this isn't an issue in V3.

Comment: Glad this has been fixed.  *sigh*

Comment: This is _not_ fixed in v3 or v4 for that matter. They only fixed it in foreach, not for piping. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A quick note to Keith's answer to complete it

Personally, I would return *nothing*. It makes sense:

```
PS> function Empty { if ('a' -eq 'b') { 'equal' } }
PS> Empty | % { write-host result is $_ }
```

But now you are in problems if you assign result from `Empty` to a variable:

```
PS> $v = Empty
PS> $v | % { write-host result is $_ }
```

There is a little trick to make it work. Just wrap the result from `Empty` as a array like this:

```
PS> $v = @(Empty)
PS> $v | % { write-host result is $_ }
PS> $v.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType
-------- -------- ----      --------
True     True     Object[]  System.Array
PS> $v.Length
0
```

Comment: That's the approach I use today *if* I don't control the definition of the command being invoked.  Otherwise I return an empty array if the function normall returns multiple items such that I would foreach over it - been bit too many times forgetting to wrap in @(). :-)

Comment: @Keith, I think you wrote great article about this tricky behaviour. You can link it here, others should read it, definitely ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
$objects | Foreach-Object -Begin{If($_ -eq $null){continue}} -Process {do your stuff here}
```

More info in [about_Continue](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347559.aspx)