# PowerShell null doesn't get piped

Tags: powershell

So one of the very first pitfalls you learn to avoid with PowerShell is that this foreach:

```
$null | foreach { "hello" }
```

will execute once. However I was trying to explain this concept to a colleague and had the following thing happen:

```
PS> $a = 1..9 | ? {$_ -eq 10}
PS> $a | % { "hello" }
PS>
```

i've tried to understand what's going on with the following but `$a` seems to be `$null`, plain and simple.

```
PS> $a = 1..9 | ? {$_ -eq 10}
PS> $a -eq $null
True
PS> $a.gettype()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $a.gettype()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

PS> $a | gm
gm : No object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet.
At line:1 char:6
+ $a | gm
+      ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand

PS> $a | % { "hello" }
PS> $null | % { "hello" }
hello
PS>
```

Are there two different "types" of null somehow? Is `$a` really an array that's being obfuscated from me for some reason?

Comment: I've always considered `GetType` to be the most reliable way for finding out a variable's type, ignoring the fuzziness of a scripting language. i must be wrong?

Comment: FYI this is no more true from PS V3

Comment: See a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356758/how-to-handle-null-in-the-pipeline

Comment: Sigh... I wish that was in 2.0

Comment: See my answer to this question, it's basically the same question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343187/why-is-an-empty-powershell-pipeline-not-the-same-as-null

Comment: thanks, didn't know what to search for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some history on this -

Given `PS > $a = 1..9 | ? {$_ -eq 10}`

Powershell 2.0 behavior

```
PS > $a | % { "hello" }
hello
PS > $null | % { "hello" }
hello
```

Powershell 3.0 behavior - "fixed" the issue when variable is null, but built-in $null still iterates

```
PS > $a | % { "hello" }
PS > $null | % { "hello" }
hello
```

In the [ForEach-Object documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731(v=wps.620).aspx) in 3.0 they added this -

> Because Windows PowerShell treats null as an explicit placeholder, the
>   ForEach-Object cmdlet generates a value for $null, just as it does for
>   other objects that you pipe to it.

```
PS C:\> 1, 2, $null, 4 | ForEach-Object {"Hello"} 
Hello 
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

The about_automatic_variables documentation for $null was also updated for 3.0.

Powershell 2.0 $null documentation

```
$NULL
   Contains a NULL or empty value. You can use this variable to
   represent NULL in commands and scripts instead of using the string
   "NULL". The string can be interpreted as TRUE if it is converted to a
   non-empty string or a non-zero integer.
```

Powershell 3.0 $null documentation

```
$NULL
       $null is an automatic variable that contains a NULL or empty value. You
       can use this variable to represent an absent or undefined value in commands
       and scripts.

       Windows PowerShell treats $null as an object with a value, that is, as an
       explicit placeholder, so you can use $null to represent an empty value in a
       series of values.  

       For example, when $null is included in a collection, it is counted as one of
       the objects.

           C:\PS> $a = ".dir", $null, ".pdf"
           C:\PS> $a.count
           3

       If you pipe the $null variable to the ForEach-Object cmdlet, it generates a
       value for $null, just as it does for the other objects.

           PS C:\ps-test> ".dir", "$null, ".pdf" | Foreach {"Hello"}
           Hello
           Hello
           Hello

       As a result, you cannot use $null to mean "no parameter value." A parameter
       value of $null overrides the default parameter value.

       However, because Windows PowerShell treats the $null variable as a placeholder,
       you can use it scripts like the following one, which would not work if $null
       were ignored.

           $calendar = @($null, $null, “Meeting”, $null, $null, “Team Lunch”, $null)
           $days = Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"
           $currentDay = 0

           foreach($day in $calendar)
           {
               if($day –ne $null)
               {
                   "Appointment on $($days[$currentDay]): $day"
               }

               $currentDay++
           } 

           Appointment on Tuesday: Meeting
           Appointment on Friday: Team lunch
```

**Note** - they also made `foreach` keyword behave the same as ForEach-Object in 3.0 (skipping $null valued variables but converts the $null built-in to a iterable value) but they didn't mention the new behavior in the documentation like they did with ForEach-Obect.

Comment: I don't understand... according to that logic, wouldn't `$aosfjiuhf | % { "hello" }` yield nothing too?

Comment: @Nacht check out new answer

Comment: Thanks, that does help me understand the change in 3.0 a little better. It sounded like something that would break lots of stuff, but that makes more sense. However I am using 2.0, so it doesn't really answer my question. The answer in the comment above by Jason Shirk seems to be what's causing my issue. $nulls are a lot more complicated than i thought!

Comment: @Nacht if you're on 2.0 your question example isn't right - in 2.0 `$a | % { "hello" }` will return one 'hello'

Comment: My mistake! here's my problem. I forgot that I had installed v3.0 on my win7 machine a while back. sorry!

Comment: @Nacht ok so this should explain the behavior you are seeing then

Comment: Powershell version 5.1 seems to have the same behavior as version 2 for this