# Writing $null to Powershell Output Stream

Tags: powershell

There are powershell cmdlets in our project for finding data in a database. If no data is found, the cmdlets write out a $null to the output stream as follows:

```
Write-Output $null
```

Or, more accurately since the cmdlets are implemented in C#:

```
WriteOutput(null)
```

I have found that this causes some behavior that is very counter to the conventions employed elsewhere, including in the built-in cmdlets.

**Are there any guidelines/rules, especially from Microsoft, that talk about this?  I need help better explaining why this is a bad idea, or to be convinced that writing $null to the output stream is an okay practice.  Here is some detail about the resulting behaviors that I see:**

If the results are piped into another cmdlet, that cmdlet executes despite no results being found and the pipeline variable ($_) is $null.  This means that I have to add checks for $null.

```
Find-DbRecord -Id 3 | For-Each { if ($_ -ne $null) { <do something with $_> }}
```

Similarly, If I want to get the array of records found, ensuring that it is an array, I might do the following:

```
$recsFound = @(Find-DbRecord -Category XYZ)
foreach ($record in $recsFound)
{
    $record.Name = "Something New"
    $record.Update()
}
```

The convention I have seen, this should work without issue.  If no records are found, the foreach loop wouldn't execute.  Since the Find cmdlet is writing null to the output, the $recsFound variable is set to an array with one item that is $null.  Now I would need to check each item in the array for $null which clutters my code.

Comment: Relevant: [PowerShell null doesn't get piped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657560/powershell-null-doesnt-get-piped)

Answer (score 0):

`$null` is not void. If you don't want null values in your pipeline, either don't write null values to the pipeline in the first place, or remove them from the pipeline with a filter like this:

```
... | Where-Object { $_ -ne $null } | ...
```

Depending on what you want to allow through the filter you could simplify it to this:

```
... | Where-Object { $_ } | ...
```

or (using the `?` alias for `Where-Object`) to this:

```
... | ? { $_ } | ...
```

which would remove all values that PowerShell interprets as `$false` (`$null`, 0, empty string, empty array, etc.).

Comment: I agree that this could be done.  What I'm looking for is justification one way or another, within the context of a Find or even a Get where the idea is to get any results found, why you would write a $null to the output if no results are found.  It should effectively be an empty array.  This is most easily accomplished by not writing anything to the pipeline.

Comment: I can only give you my personal opinion on that, which is: don't write unless you do have a result.

Comment: That is my opinion as well, though my goal is to find a guideline or rule from a large community or specifically from Microsoft.  Or some rationale that I haven't thought of that might help persuade others that my approach is better.